# Removing a Name from Gmail Chat

Tags: gmail, chat

In Gmail Chat, the *Never show* button has disappeared. How do I get it back?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

Click the pull down arrow next to your name and select revert to old chat.